# Alter a .txt file of a variable directory

Tags: c++, text-files

I'm trying to write a program that alters a .txt file of a variable directory.
However when I attempt to do so I get an error.

My error:

```
no matching function for call to `std::basic_ofstream<char,      std::char_traits<char> >::basic_ofstream(std::string&)'
```

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    string file_name ;
    cout << "Input the directory of the file you would like to alter:" << endl;
    cin >>  file_name ;


    ofstream myfile ( file_name );
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
    myfile << "This is a line.\n";
    myfile << "This is another line.\n";
    myfile.close();
    }
    else cout << "Unable to open file";
    return 0;

}
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: You don't have to call `myfile.close()`; the `ofstream` destructor will close the file for you automatically.  When you read input from a stream (like you do with `cin >> file_name`), you should always check to be sure the input succeeded.  When you read in a string, it's not likely that the operation will fail, but if you read in something else (like a number of some kind), failures are more likely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `fstream` constructors take C strings, not `std::string`, so you need

```
std::ofstream myfile(file_name.c_str());
```

The reason why they take C strings instead of `std::string`s is purely historical; there's no technical reason.  C++0x adds constructors that take `std::string`s.